# Is there a way to catch RuntimeErrors when using os.system?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, runtimeexception, lighthouse

I'm writing a tool that sends commands to the CMD for Google Lighthouse and want to catch the error if an URL isn't valid. What exception would I use?

I'm currently trying to catch RuntimeError in the Exception when entering an invalid URL.

```
try:
    os.system("lighthouse --quiet {} {} {} {} {} --output-path={}/{}.html ".format(DevEmuStr,throttlingVar,CacheStr,presetVar,url,reportlocation,filename))
except RuntimeError:
    print("Please provide a proper URL")
```

Instead of "Please provide a proper URL" I still get:

```
Runtime error encountered: The URL you have provided appears to be invalid.
LHError: INVALID_URL
at lighthouse (C:\Users\sugar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\lighthouse\lighthouse-core\index.js:44:11)
at chromeP.then._ (C:\Users\sugar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\lighthouse\lighthouse-cli\run.js:182:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

And Lighthouse just continues with the next URL

Is there another error I could catch?

Comment: `LHError: INVALID URL`? Seems like a great *hint*

Comment: Tried to catch the LHError now, sadly no success

Comment: os.system does not throw an exception, it returns an error code. You have to check if os.system == 0 , else try to get the stdout of the exec'd process and determine the error.

Comment: @KSugar Were we helpful, is there more you wanted to know?

Comment: You were all helpful, but sadly I still don't quite get how I would go ahead and get the exit code. I tried it with subprocess.check_output but that doesn't give me a proper output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone that tried to help me, I finally found a way to get it.

By adding this:

```
lh_url_ok = os.system("lighthouse --quiet {} {} {} {} {} --output-path={}/{}.html ".format(DevEmuStr,throttlingVar,CacheStr,presetVar,url,reportlocation,filename))
if lh_url_ok >0:
    print("Error")
```

i was able to check if the exit code was above 0 (0=no error)

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't an exception you could catch from Python.

It appears to me that "Runtime error encountered" is output printed out by lighthouse, it isn't an actual Python exception you could catch.

Python doesn't know anything about what is internally going on in the executable you start with os.system, you can just get the output and an exit code.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how I would go ahead to get the exit code? All methods i found online didn't work for me